# Events doesn't get raise

Tags: c#, events, discord.net

I am creating a Discord BOT and I want to create some more specified events, for example when the `DiscordSocketClient.UserVoiceStateUpdated` event is raised it calls a method which figures out what changed on the user (e.g. joined or left a voice channel) and raises another event. The problem is, none of the events get raised.

### Code

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User _user = new User();
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose });
        //event subscriptions
        _client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += User.VoiceStateUpdated;
        _user.Joined += UserAccountManager.User_Joined;
        _user.Left += UserAccountManager.User_Left;
    }
}
public class User
{
    public delegate void VoiceStateChangeEventHandler(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState);
    public event VoiceStateChangeEventHandler Joined;
    public event VoiceStateChangeEventHandler Left;

    //User voice state changes: joined | left | moved
    public static Task VoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
    { //<- I inserted a breakpoint here. The execution doesn't get here
        //Joined
        if(oldState.VoiceChannel == null && newState.VoiceChannel != null)
        {
            new User().RaiseJoinedEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        //Left
        if (oldState.VoiceChannel != null && newState.VoiceChannel == null)
        {
            new User().RaiseLeftEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        //Moved (Joined + Left)
        if(oldState.VoiceChannel != null && newState.VoiceChannel != null && oldState.VoiceChannel != newState.VoiceChannel)
        {
            new User().RaiseJoinedEvent(user, oldState, newState);
            new User().RaiseLeftEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected virtual void RaiseJoinedEvent(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        Joined?.Invoke(socketUser, oldSocketVoiceState, newSocketVoiceState); //<- I inserted a breakpoint here. The execution doesn't get here. I played around with the code and when the execution get here the `Joined` has null value.
    }
    protected virtual void RaiseLeftEvent(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        Left?.Invoke(socketUser, oldSocketVoiceState, newSocketVoiceState); //<- I inserted a breakpoint here. The execution doesn't get here. I played around with the code and when the execution get here the `Left` has null value.
    }
}
public static class UserAccountManager
{
    public static void User_Joined(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    { //<- I inserted a breakpoint here. The execution never get here.
        //CODE...
    }

    public static void User_Left(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    { //<- I inserted a breakpoint here. The execution never get here.
        //CODE...
    }
}
```

*I've so simplified the code as much as possible.*

Any suggestion?

Comment: a quick review - it looks like you're creating a new user and raising an event on that new user.  Nothing is subscribed to the events on those new users.  Raise the event on your existing user that has event listeners attached (created in the `Main` block).

Comment: Does your DiscordSocketClient object actually do anything? As in, don't you need to call Login or something on it? '            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "token in here"); // put your token here

            await _client.StartAsync();' (And obviously what ps2goat wrote for the user events)

Comment: @user1515791 Yes, but I removed from the code because it's not relevant for the question.

Comment: @NoelNemeth, good to see it works, but in your question you say that _client.UserVoiceStateUpdated didnt fire as well. In your solution, that part ain't changed, is it? BTW, "normally" you don't want static events, when you program grows it can bite you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the static non-static fields.

### The correct code

```
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig { LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose });
        //event subscriptions
        _client.UserVoiceStateUpdated += User.VoiceStateUpdated;
        User.Joined += UserAccountManager.User_Joined;
        User.Left += UserAccountManager.User_Left;
    }
}
public class User
{
    public delegate void VoiceStateChangeEventHandler(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState);
    public static event VoiceStateChangeEventHandler Joined;
    public static event VoiceStateChangeEventHandler Left;

    //User voice state changes: joined | left | moved
    public static Task VoiceStateUpdated(SocketUser user, SocketVoiceState oldState, SocketVoiceState newState)
    {
        //Joined
        if(oldState.VoiceChannel == null && newState.VoiceChannel != null)
        {
            RaiseJoinedEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        //Left
        if (oldState.VoiceChannel != null && newState.VoiceChannel == null)
        {
            RaiseLeftEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        //Moved (Joined + Left)
        if(oldState.VoiceChannel != null && newState.VoiceChannel != null && oldState.VoiceChannel != newState.VoiceChannel)
        {
            RaiseJoinedEvent(user, oldState, newState);
            RaiseLeftEvent(user, oldState, newState);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected static void RaiseJoinedEvent(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        Joined?.Invoke(socketUser, oldSocketVoiceState, newSocketVoiceState);
    }
    protected static void RaiseLeftEvent(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        Left?.Invoke(socketUser, oldSocketVoiceState, newSocketVoiceState);
    }
}
public static class UserAccountManager
{
    public static void User_Joined(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        //CODE...
    }

    public static void User_Left(SocketUser socketUser, SocketVoiceState oldSocketVoiceState, SocketVoiceState newSocketVoiceState)
    {
        //CODE...
    }
}
```

And thank you [ps2goat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2084315/ps2goat)!